# Trouble evaluating decimal values in java

Tags: java

```
double  x = 0.00090; 
double b = 0.00100;
double c = x - b;
```

produces

```
-1.0000000000000005E-4
```

instead of

```
-0.0001
```

and

```
double  x = -0.09;       
double b = 0.001;
double c = x * b;
```

produces

```
-8.999999999999999E-5
```

instead of

```
-0.00009
```

I also tried with

```
Math.round(c) and Math.round(c*100.0)/100.0
```

but it is producing same results or results with incomplete number range after decimal.

Comment: how is `0.00090 - 0.00100` equals `-0001`? it is equal to `-0.0001` which is equal to `-1.00 E-4`.

Comment: use `System.out.println(String.format("%.5f", c));` to read answers and you will see what you want.

Comment: @Blip what if when it will be like 4-3 then it will produce 1.00000 which is sound not good for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how numeric operations are defined in the specification.

**Decimal numbers are internally represented as the closest approximation, which in some cases is not the exact literal value.**

If you need precise numeric computation, you have to use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are correct. You might want to read up on how doubles are stored in binary digits. its because it's base 2. If we used something like base 3, then in normal digits, 2/3 would be 0.66666666... but in the "tridigit" it would be 0.2

Answer (score 1):

The `E` notation is confusing you (explanation on how it works [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5))

```
-1.0000000000000005E-4
```

is

```
-0.00010000000000000005
```

in standard notation and

```
-8.999999999999999E-5
```

is

```
-0.00008999999999999999
```

in standard notation. All the answer you see are correct (almost, but they are very close, decimal math [isn't always precise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)), just using the `E` notation.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    double  x = 0.00090; 
    double b = 0.00100;

    BigDecimal xd = new BigDecimal(x).setScale(10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(b).setScale(10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal cd = xd.multiply(bd);
    double c = cd.doubleValue();

    System.out.println(c);
```

For precise calculations, like money calculations, you should use BigDecimals, because they have desired precision, and don't lost any accuracy.

If you prefer printing without "E", try this line:

```
    System.out.println(cd.toPlainString());
```